# C# Int Array Return Indices of Summed Members Equaling Target

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, integer, indexof

Okay, new to programming, new to Stack. I've looked for repeat questions, but they seem to be for python and JS.

I am close to finishing my first `leetcode` exercise.  I know I'm terrible, but I've spent close to 4 hours on Arrays.

This last exercise wants me to take in an int[] and an int target, returning the indices of the two array members that add up to the target.

I've foregone Sorting, and just put them in order. I want to get the basic down and then add in a sort.

Problem: When I run the below code, I just get -1, -1. But when I breakpoint, I see that the variables are holding the correct information, so I am kind of at a standstill, having used the debug tools available to me.

Any guidance or suggestions are welcome, I'm not looking for anyone to "figure it out" for me. If you wanna lead me by the nose, I won't be offended.

```
public class Solution
{
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
    {

        int low = 0;
        int high = nums.Length - 1;

        while (low < high)
        {
            var sum = nums[low] + nums[high];

            if (sum == target)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", Array.IndexOf(nums, low), Array.IndexOf(nums, high));
                break;

            }
            else if (sum < target)
            {
                low++;
            }
            else
            {
                high--;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] nums = { 3, 12, 23, 34, 45 };
        Solution ui = new Solution();
        ui.TwoSum(nums, 15);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the expected result? What do you want it to print to the console?

Comment: It needs to return the indices of the two array members that add up to the target int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you already have the indices in the high and low variables.
`Array.IndexOf(nums, low)` is trying to find the index of the index value which doesn't exist. -1 is the return value when what you're searching for is not found in the array.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I know this was a really basic problem.  I just took a 3 month course, I can program a functional good looking mvc, but this specific c# stuff needs practice. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another suggestion to solve the problem.
I don't think that you really need to sort stuff just in order to find two elements that sum up to a specific target.

Also this is kind of easier IMO.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] nums = {3, 23, 12, 34, 45};
        var result = TwoSum(nums, 15);
        if (result.Length == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("no combination did sum up to the target sum");
            
        Console.WriteLine(result[0] + " " + result[1]);
    }

    public static int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        for (int outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < nums.Length; outerIndex++)
        {
            for (int innerIndex = 1; innerIndex < nums.Length; innerIndex++) {
                if (nums[outerIndex] + nums[innerIndex] == target)
                    return new int[2]{outerIndex, innerIndex};              
            }
        }
        
        return new int[0]{};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want you can just update the `Console` line to be:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", low, high);
```